# Cannot install any new packages due to attribute error

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try to install a package on my python project I get the following error:

```
File "c:\users\user\ideaprojects\finvizscrapr\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 487, in prepare_request
files=request.listFiles,
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'listFiles'
```

Very strange since I've installed a lot of other packages before, but after closing down my IDE I can't install any new package using `pip install <package>`.

I'm using a virtual environment.

Comment: I seem to remember that pip bundles its own install of requests, so it seems strnge that they could be out of sync.  Have you upgraded Python or pip recently, or done anything else that might have affected pip?

Comment: `pip` never had such code: https://github.com/pypa/pip/search?q=listFiles Can we see `pip --version`? Can we see the content of your version of `c:\users\user\ideaprojects\finvizscrapr\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py`? In my version of the file the line 487 is `files=request.files`.

Comment: Pip version is 22.3.1 and python 3.9 in virtual environment. Line 487 is the same as yours

Comment: I had the same issue. Not a solution, but I just recreated the venv. If necessary save your requirements first with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, recreate the venv, then reinstall the requirements with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.